# Direct Map Cache and cache misses

Tags: caching, mips, cpu-architecture

I am working on my homework, but I am not sure how to calculate the total cache misses. I have been trying to understand it but it just is not making sense to me. I am given some Mips code and I need to calculate the number of cache misses. Here is the problem:

Direct-map cache.  We are given a direct-map cache with 1024 blocks.  Each 
block is a MIPS word (32 bits).  The cache uses write-back whenever a write miss 
happens.  The main memory consists of 2^30 words.  Initially, the cache is empty.
Determine the total number of cache misses for the following instruction sequences.

```
lw $s0, 4($sp) 
lw $s0, 8($sp) 
sw $s0, 8($sp) 
sw $s1, 4($sp) 
lw $s0, 4($sp)
```

I am not looking for the answer. I want to learn how to do this because I have many more problems like this on the homework assignment. I would like a walkthrough on this. In the meantime I will be researching this topic trying to figure out the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing alignment of $SP it's impossible to tell how many cache misses you will have.
If SP is aligned on 32-byte boundary, then there will be only one cache line miss on the very first access. If SP contains address 0x18, then you will have two cache line misses because 4($sp) and 8($sp) will access different cache lines.