# How to find cache hit and miss for MIPS instructions?

Tags: caching, assembly, mips

My question is regarding a homework assignment in my computer architecture class. If someone could just explain to me how to work this problem I would really appreciate it!

Problem: Suppose main memory consists of 2^24 words.  We are given a direct-map cache with 2^10 = 1024 blocks.  Each block is a MIPS word (32 bits).
The cache uses write-back whenever a write miss happens.  Initially, the cache is 
empty.  Assume that the address stored in $sp is 0 mod 4, so that the `4($sp)` 
address is also 0 mod 4, and so on. 
For each instruction in the following sequences, label it as a cache hit or miss.  If it 
is a miss, indicate the block that is written or read (e.g. in terms of its memory 
address range).

```
lw $s0, 4($sp)
lw $s0, 8($sp)
sw $s0, 8($sp)
sw $s1, 4($sp)
lw $s0, 4($sp)
```

How do I know whether each instruction is a cache hit or miss? I'm not even really sure what this means.

Comment: Each memory address is associated with a specific slot in the cache. Initially the slots are all empty, but when reading or writing to an address the slot will be filled. Your assignment is to figure out if the slot is filled or not for each instruction, while also considering that several addresses might share the same slot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Direct Map Cache and cache misses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274191/direct-map-cache-and-cache-misses)

Comment: OK. so correct me if I am wrong... but i believe the first one would be a miss since it is the first time using that slot, second one miss, then would the third be a hit or miss because the 8 slot was used by the lw command? Or does it have to be the same command? Then I am guessing the fourth one would be a hit because the 4 slot has been used... then the fifth would be a miss because it starts over?